# Como alterar fonte em PDF gerado pelo iReport?

Tags: ireport, pdf

Criei um relatório utilizando o iReport e alterei a fonte do texto para uma fonte customizada aqui da empresa.

O relatório é visualizado utilizando o próprio visualizador do iReport e funciona tranquilamente com a fonte que coloquei, porém ao gerar o relatório em PDF a fonte que coloquei é alterada para o padrão do sistema.

Já coloquei a fonte no *path* do iReport, e a fonte customizada está instalada no Windows. Estou utilizando o iReport 5.1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fiz um teste para reproduzir seu caso como explico nos tópicos a seguir:

## Incluindo uma fonte no iReport

Primeiro fiz o download de uma fonte qualquer, neste caso, chamada **Royal Chicken**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois, acessei a tela de configuração do iReport, especificamente a aba de fontes:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Clicando em `Install Font`, eu coloquei o caminho do arquivo `.ttf`, conforme a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que um passo muito importante é marcar a fonte como sendo *embutível* num PDF. Veja a opção abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei porque isso ocorre, mas sem marcar essa opção, o Jasper Reports não gera o PDF com a fonte correta, mesmo que a opção de "embutir" do campo não esteja ativada. Em teoria, ele deveria tentar colocar a fonte sem embuti-la, mas isso não acontece.

Concluindo o *wizard*, a fonte aparece instalada conforma a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E então é possível selecioná-la na lista, conforma a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após seguir esses passos, pude ver o relatório corretamente gerado em PDF **dentro do iReport**.

## Exportando a fonte para uso fora do iReport

Na tela de configuração de fontes, clique em `Export as extension` para criar um arquivo `.jar` contendo a fonte.

Dentro do arquivo gerado, se a opção *Embed this font in the PDF Document* foi ativada, deve haver um arquivo XML (dentro de uma pasta chamada `fonts`), com um conteúdo parecido com este:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fontFamilies>

   <fontFamily name="Royal Chicken">
       <normal><![CDATA[fonts/Royal Chicken.ttf]]></normal>
       <pdfEmbedded><![CDATA[true]]></pdfEmbedded>
   </fontFamily>

</fontFamilies>
```

## Configurando um projeto de teste

Após realizar esses passos, criei um projeto no meu Eclipse para testar a exportação do relatório.

Este é o `pom.xml`:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>br.com.starcode</groupId>
  <artifactId>jasper-font-test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>fonte</groupId>
        <artifactId>fonte</artifactId>
        <version>0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/fonte.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Depois, conforma a configuração acima, coloquei o arquivo exportado `fonte.jar` na pasta `lib` que fica na raiz do projeto.

Coloquei ainda o fonte (XML) do relatório em `/src/main/resources/relatorio.jrxml`.

Criei ainda uma classe `Bean`, servindo como uma entidade fictícia para popular o relatório.

Finalmente, executei o seguinte método para gerar o PDF com a nova fonte:

```java
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter;


public class Teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JRException, FileNotFoundException {

        //lista com dados do relatório
        List<Bean> beans = new ArrayList<Bean>();

        //adicionar dados fictícios

        //encapsula lista num JRDataSource
        JRDataSource jrDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(beans);

        //compila relatório
        JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(Teste.class.getResourceAsStream("relatorio.jrxml"));

        //cria a "impressora" do jasperreports
        Map<String, Object> mapaParametros = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        JasperPrint jrprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, mapaParametros, jrDataSource); 

        //cria um exportador para PDF
        JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();

        //define a saída para um arquivo
        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, new FileOutputStream("teste.pdf"));
        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jrprint);

        //exporta
        exporter.exportReport();

    }

}
```

O resultado pode ser visto na imagem a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Conclusão

Se você já havia seguido os passos acima, talvez tenha faltado apenas marcar a opção de embutir a fonte no PDF. Caso contrário, revise os passos e você vai conseguir fazer isso.

Comment: Após uma breve olhada no dicionário me pareceu melhor "embutir" do que "embarcar" como tradução para "embed", o que acha?

Comment: [*Embutir, embarcar  ou embeber*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_embarcado), eis a questão...

Comment: *Se a vontade do povo é que seja "embutir", então será "embutir"...*

Comment: O passo a passo tá certo, porém o erro persiste. Vou ter que ver se em outra máquina o problema não ocorre. Obrigado pela resposta

Comment: @adelmo00 Já tentou colocar outra fonte? O arquivo pode ter algum problema.

Comment: já coloquei. Baixei outras e o problema persiste

Comment: É a fonte que me passaram mesmo. Tem algumas fontes que funcionam e outras não

Comment: A fonte pode estar num formato incompatível com as APIs do jasper. Se quiser fazer uma última tentativa, pode tentar converter a fonte para outro formato e depois para TTF novamente. Existem alguns conversores online, como [este](http://www.freefontconverter.com/).

Comment: Ressuscitando tópico. Consegui colocar a fonte sem erros, porém agora ocorre o seguinte erro: Font 'Custom Sans SemiBold' is not available to the JVM. See the Javadoc for more details.