# Como definir tamanho da fonte no PDF?

Tags: java, pdf, ireport

Estou fazendo um relatório utilizando iReport esta tudo ok, porém na aplicação ao gerar PDF a fonte não fica a mesma do preview do iReport, o tipo da fonte esta ok, gostaria de saber uma forma de definir o tamanho da fonte a ser exibida no PDF.

Comment: Isso acontece quando você vai em "Text Properties" do seu elemento, na propriedade "Size" e aumenta por ali ?

Comment: Isso! ja instalei uma nova fonte gerei o .jar dela e inseri no meu projeto, o estilo da fonte muda porém o tamanho da fonte no pdf sempre fica 10px, alguém sabe como corrigir esta questão do tamanho da fonte ?

Answer (score 1):

Segundo um post feito nesse link, pode ser útil pra você: [Link export PDF](http://www.guj.com.br/java/78191-jasper--ireport--export-para-pdf)

> O problema é que o IReport utiliza Java/AWT para a montagem e pré-visualização do relatório e o gerador de PDF não, o que obriga a definir uma fonte especifica para PDF. Na versão 3.7.1 do IReport estes métodos estão "deprecated" o que se faz necessário criar uma biblioteca JAR/Zip com as fontes utilizadas (e criar um xml com algumas configurações) e adicioná-las ao classpath da aplicação.
>
> > O interessante é que a versão 3.7.1 possui um utilitário para realizar esta tarefa, através do menu Ferramentas --> Opções --> iReport --> Fonts. Basta clicar em install font, selecionar a Fonte (e suas variações, tipo Negrito, Itálico, etc.) e gerar o arquivo jar/zip a ser adicionado ao classpath.
>
> A partir deste momento, basta executar a aplicação que o relatório irá respeitar as formatações escolhidas no processo de geração do PDF. Lembre-se de ativar a opção "embedded pdf" nas opções do ireport e se o campo formatado tiver tags html, ativar a opção do campo pra ler TAGS html...

Há também um tópico neste site que pode ser interessante para você: [Alterar fonte iReport](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2303/como-alterar-fonte-em-pdf-gerado-pelo-ireport?rq=1)

Comment: Ja fiz o processo acima, mais o tamanho da fonte no pdf sempre permanece padrão de 10px

Comment: @Brunno você pode utilizar tmb o link outro link que disponibilizei na minha resposta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2303/como-alterar-fonte-em-pdf-gerado-pelo-ireport?rq=1