# Fontes em relatórios do jasperreports no wildfly

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, wildfly

Tenho um projeto web em java que roda em servidor linux.
Este projeto tem relatórios criados no Ireport com fontes customizadas, porém estas fontes não são exibidas quando chamo os relatórios neste projeto.
Já segui o tutorial exposto aqui [Como alterar fonte em PDF gerado pelo iReport?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2303/como-alterar-fonte-em-pdf-gerado-pelo-ireport)
Porém mesmo adicionando o JAR no build path do projeto as fontes não são reconhecidas.

OBS: Estou exportando os relatórios em pdf, e quando criei o jar das fontes no IReport tomei o cuidado de marcar a opção para "embutir" as fontes. 
OBS2: Estou usando fontes comuns como a Times New Roman(peguei a fonte padrão de um micro windows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o meu problema. Descobri que ao criar o jar com as fontes personalizadas pelo IReport ou JasperSoftStudio não podemos dar nomes as fontes que tenham espaços. No meu caso por exemplo eu estava criando uma fonte com o nome "Times New Roman". Quando nomeei a fonte como "TimesNewRoman" funcionou perfeitamente.
Sendo assim o tutorial descrito no link [Como alterar fonte em PDF gerado pelo iReport?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2303/como-alterar-fonte-em-pdf-gerado-pelo-ireport) está correto, porém apenas deve-se lembrar de não colocar espaços nos nomes das fontes.

Answer (score 0):

Além dos passos descritos na referência incluída na pergunta, também inclua a pasta src/main/resources/fonts e dentro dela copie de C:\Windows\Fonts as fontes que precisar utilizar no relatório.

Inclua também o arquivo nessa pasta um arquivo chamado fontsfamily.xml contendo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fontFamilies>
   <fontFamily name="Arial">
       <normal><![CDATA[fonts/arial.ttf]]></normal>
       <bold><![CDATA[fonts/arialbd.ttf]]></bold>
       <italic><![CDATA[fonts/ariali.ttf]]></italic>
       <boldItalic><![CDATA[fonts/arialbi.ttf]]></boldItalic>
       <pdfEmbedded><![CDATA[true]]></pdfEmbedded>
   </fontFamily>
</fontFamilies>
```

Comment: Fiz da forma como falou, porém não funcionou. Criei também o arquivo jasperreports_extension.properties e coloquei em src/main/resources/
Nenhuma alternativa funcionou.
O meu projeto é um EJB que roda dentro de um EAR no servidor, não sei se influencia em algo.